# Windows batch version of Unix select command?

Tags: bash, batch-file

I'm trying to create a Windows version of a simple bash script I have, but I cannot seem to find a Windows version of the Unix 'select' command.  Is there one?

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter the number of the file you want to select:"

select THE_FILE in someDir/*;
do
    echo "You picked $THE_FILE ($REPLY)"
    # Will do some stuff here.
    break;
done
```

It was very easy to find this Linux example, so I am a bit perplexed that I cannot seem to find a Windows equivalent.

Edit: The select command prompts the user to select a file from a given directory (that's an oversimplification).  To clarify, the script from above will produce the following output, assuming there is a subdirectory 'someDir' with only those three text files in it.

```
Enter the number of the file you want to select:
1) someDir/somefile1.txt
2) someDir/somefile2.txt
3) someDir/somefile3.txt
#? 2
You picked someDir/somefile2.txt (2)
```

Comment: What does `select` do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows batch commands does not include any equivalent to the `select` command. So you will have to build your own version.

You will need:

- `call` command. Create a subroutine and reuse it
- `for` command to iterate over the files, or `for /f` to iterate over the output of another command returning the list of files
- For short lists, `choice` command is more friendly to the user as it is not needed to press enter, but for longer lists or if you don't know the number of files to select,  `set /p` is a better option

Here, just a sample

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    call :select "someDir\*" THE_FILE
    echo You picked %THE_FILE%

    goto :eof


:select mask returnVar
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Configure internal variables
    set "fileNumber="
    set "maxFiles=-1"
    for /f "delims==" %%a in ('2^>nul set f[') do set "%%a="

    echo Enter the number of the file you want to select:

    rem Search files, show list and create array with file list
    rem Using xcopy to get the list of files because it will show
    rem relative paths when a relative mask is used as input 
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in ('
        xcopy "%~1" "%temp%" /l ^| findstr /n /r /c:"[\\\.:]"
    ') do (
        echo %%a^) %%b
        set "f[%%a]=%%~fb"
        set "maxFiles=%%a"
    )

    rem Prompt 
    :select.ask
    set /p "fileNumber=#? "

    rem Validate input
    set /a "fileNumber=fileNumber+0" 2>nul
    if %fileNumber% gtr %maxFiles% set "fileNumber=-1"
    if %fileNumber% lss 1 set "fileNumber="
    if not defined fileNumber (
        echo Wrong selection
        goto :select.ask
    )

    rem Retrieve file from array
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    for %%a in ("!f[%fileNumber%]!") do (
        endlocal 
        set "selectedFile=%%~a"
    )

    rem Return selection to caller
    endlocal & set "%~2=%selectedFile%"
    goto :eof
```

Comment: Wow, funny how complicated some things are in Windows vs Linux, and vice versa.  Works great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See `Choice /?` or `set /?`.

```
choice /c:yn
If errorelevel 1 if not errorlevel  2 echo Y was chosen
```

Comment: I don't think these commands accomplish what I'm after (but perhaps might be part of a solution).  I updated the question to more clearly reflect the behavior I'm looking to replicate.  Thanks!

Comment: Thewre is no command like that. You can write your own easily or stuff about making `choice` work.

Comment: If I knew how do do it easily, I wouldn't have posted this question!   I do very little batch programming (or bash for that matter).

Comment: You can use dir /b to print out files and choice to take the answer.

Comment: `dir /b` just lists _filenames_ (e.g., `foo.txt`), whereas the desired behavior is to prepend an index to each filename (e.g., `1) foo.txt`), because the user selects the desired file by _index_.

Answer (score 1):

Although a bash `select` equivalent is not included in Windows Batch, it is very easy to write your own. It may be a subroutine with the exact same parameters of Linux `select` so you don't need to learn something new in order to use it; this way, the "in" word in second parameter will not be used in the Batch code.

```
@echo off

call :select THE_FILE in someDir/*
echo You picked %THE_FILE% (%errorlevel%)

goto :EOF


rem Subroutine that emulates Linux's select
:select returnVar in directory

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

echo Enter the number of the file you want to select:

rem Show the files and create an array with them
set n=0
for %%a in (%3) do (
   set /A n+=1
   set file[!n!]=%%a
   echo !n!^) %%a
)

rem Get the number of the desired file
:getNumber
set /P "number=#? "
if not defined file[%number%] goto getNumber

rem Return selected file to caller
for /F "delims=" %%a in ("!file[%number%]!") do endlocal & set "%1=%%a" & exit /B %number%
```

Previous code is straigthforward, but post a comment here if you have any doubt about it. Perhaps the most complex part is the `for /F` command at last line, that is required to save the value of the `!filename[%number%]!` in the `%%a` FOR parameter before execute the `endlocal` and the assignment to the first parameter, that is the way to return that value to the calling program. If `endlocal` would be executed first, the `!delayed expansion!` of the variable will no longer work...

Although this code does not return the path of the selected file, it is very easy to add such feature, but the code will complicate a little.

Answer (score 1):

While a batch-file solution is desired by the OP, it is worth presenting a **[*PowerShell*](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd742419.aspx) solution** that is **much more concise**:

```
($files = get-childitem -file someDir\) | % { $i=0 } { ++$i; "$i) $_" }
$reply = read-host -p "Enter the number of the file you want to select"
"You picked $($files[$reply-1]) ($reply)"
```

- `$files = get-childitem -file someDir\` collects all files in directory `someDir` in variable `$files`

  - Note that the `-file` option for restricting child items to *files* requires PowerShell 3.0 or higher; on earlier versions, pipe to `? { -not $_.PSIsContainer }` instead.
- `% { $i=0 } { ++$i; "$i) $_" }` outputs each filename prefixed with its 1-based index.

  - `%` is shorthand for the `ForEach-Object` object cmdlet, which processes a block of code for each input object
  - `{ $i=0 }` initializes the index variable (executed *once*, before iteration)
  - `{ ++$i; "$i) $_" }` is executed for *each* input object, `$_`; `++$i` increments the index, `"$i) $_"` prints the index followed by `)` and a space, followed by the input object's default property, which is the filename in this case. (If you wanted to print the *full path* instead, for instance, you'd use `"$i) $($_.fullname)"`).
  - Note how no explicit output (print) command is needed - the results are output to the terminal by default.
- `$reply = read-host -p "Enter the number of the file you want to select"` reads a single line from the terminal with the specified prompt and stores the user's input in variable `$reply`.
- `"You picked $($files[$reply-1]) ($reply)"` outputs the result; again, no explicit output command is required.